# Rspec custom failure message error when match runs matchers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am using Steak to do acceptance testing because I didn't like cucumber at all although I am using some cucumber concepts in the way I test. I liked the declarative vs imperative styles for testings and I am abstracting some expectations into elaborated custom rspec matchers that insinde the match method use other matchers, heres an example:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :show_post do |post|
  match do |page|
    within '.post' do
      page.should have_content post.title
      page.should have_content post.tagline
      page.should have_content post.body
      page.should list_author  post.author
    end
  end
end
```

The only problem I am having is that if my matcher fails I get a generic message that doesn't give me any insight on what's missing, when what I really want is to now which one of the expectation that compose the custom matcher is not meet.

I've been living with this nuisance for a while because I really like the expressiveness of being able to do:

```
page.should show_post Post.last
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better yet:

```
module DefineMatcher
  def define_matcher name, &block
    klass = Class.new do
      include Capybara::RSpecMatchers

      attr_reader :expected

      def initialize expected
        @expected = expected
      end

      define_method :matches?, &block
    end

    define_method name do |expected|
      klass.new expected
    end
  end
end


module PageMatchers
  extend DefineMatcher

  define_matcher :show_notice do |page|
    within '.alert-notice' do
      page.should have_content expected
    end
  end
end

RSpec.configuration.include PageMatchers, :type => :acceptance
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
class ShowsPost
  include Capybara::RSpecMatchers

  def initialize post
    @post = post
  end

  def matches? page
    page.should have_content @post.title
    page.should have_content @post.tagline
    page.should have_content @post.body
    page.should list_author  @post.author
  end
end

def show_post post
  ShowsPost.new(post)
end
```

Comment: Allthough not ideal since I prefer the macro for making matchers.